# Pandas dataframe: Is there a difference in performance in replacing values by column and row?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

print(df)

     dog      A         B           C
0     dog1    0.787575  0.159330    0.053095
1     dog10   0.770698  0.169487    0.059815
2     dog11   0.792689  0.152043    0.055268
3     dog12   0.785066  0.160361    0.054573
4     dog13   0.795455  0.150464    0.054081
5     dog14   0.794873  0.150700    0.054426
..    ....
8     dog19   0.811585  0.140207    0.048208
9     dog2    0.797202  0.152033    0.050765
10    dog20   0.801607  0.145137    0.053256
11    dog21   0.792689  0.152043    0.055268
    ....
```

I know for row `0` and in column `df['dog']`, the first value needs to be explicitly changed. Instead of `dog1`, it should be `dog11`.

What are all the ways a user can change this value? Is there a substantial difference in performance between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if want select by column name:

```
df.ix[0, 'dog'] = 'dog11'
df.loc[0, 'dog'] = 'dog11'
```

Fastest is [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html), if you want select by position: `dog` position (e.g. in this sample first column - `0`):

```
df.iat[0, 0] = 'dog11'
```

**Timings**:

```
In [144]: %%timeit
     ...: df.ix[0, 'dog'] = 'dog11'
The slowest run took 5.37 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 308 µs per loop

In [146]: %%timeit
     ...: df.loc[0, 'dog'] = 'dog11'
     ...: 
The slowest run took 5.03 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 305 µs per loop

In [145]: %%timeit
     ...: df.iat[0, 0] = 'dog11'
The slowest run took 53.64 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.18 µs per loop

In [151]: %%timeit
     ...: df.iloc[0, 0] = 'dog11'
     ...: 
The slowest run took 5.69 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 392 µs per loop
```

Comment: `Fastest is iat, but column dog has to be first` Why do you say this?